# Fcm_id is not genrate when i am login with mobile browerser

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
     if (currentToken) {
       $('#fcm_id').val(currentToken);
       sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
       updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
     } else {
       // Show permission request.
       console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
       // Show permission UI.
       updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
       setTokenSentToServer(false);
     }
```

The code is working fine with Pc Browers but not genrate fcm_id when i will try to login with  mobile browser.i am searched too much but noboday getting that type of issue.
Anyone can help me to getting out this issue.

Comment: What mobile browser on what device did you test this with? What's output you get there?

Comment: Yes i tested i put the fcm id which is genrated in  firebase file in alert it is showing on my laptop broweser but not showing on the mobile browser.

Comment: What mobile browser on what device did you test this with?

Comment: i am tested on google chrome

Comment: Thanks. And on what device (type)?

Comment: All the devices i tried.